# Windows Desktop app or Windows Store app

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, desktop-application

My app, basically, needs to do the following:

1. getting GPS coordinates
2. calling web services (for accessing, sending info etc)
3. work in background with no UI for most of the time

The target device is a mobile tablet running with Windows 8.1.

I found out that for this OS I can develop both a desktop app or a Windows Store App.

Please, what do you suggest to use for my needs?

Also, because I dont know Windows Desktop App at all, Please can I get everything done using a desktop app?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the main difference between those two is, whether or not you get a window in your old-school desktop (desktop app) or one of those fancy full-screen-app thingies that were introduced in Windows 8... Afaik you can't sell the Desktop apps on the Windows Store, but functionality-wise your average desktop app has no real downside as you can use .NET with all fancy features for both...
[Here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/windows-8-store-vs-desktop-app-development) you can find a detailed comparison between both. But from your description you should be fine with the desktop app (:

Cheers D

Comment: you can publish on the store according to this http://www.samlogic.net/articles/windows-8-desktop-app-vs-store-app.htm

Comment: Oh :) Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the desktop app simply for the background tasks you mentioned. This is tricky to do in Windows Store apps as Windows tombstones (freezes) the apps if you navigate away for any length of time. As far as I know, only certain apps, such as music apps, can run in the background.

Desktop apps have no such limitation.